# Delete specific record in sqlite table based on two criteria: _id and column

Tags: android, sqlite

I have created a sqlite table for my android app, this table has 5 columns and multiple rows, the columns being: _id, column1, column2, column3, column4.

I want to delete a specific record, for instance the record stored in column3 corresponding to _id (in a different class are the getters and setters, for this I've named the class "TableHandler")

I guess that I'm a bit confused, following is what I was planning, but for column3 I'm not sure what should be the argument, I just want to delete whatever is  in that column position corresponding to _id

```
 public void deleteValueColumn3(TableHandler value){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_NAME, KEY_ID + " = ? AND " + KEY_COLUMN3 + " = ?",
                new String[] {String.valueOf(value.getID()), ?????????);
        db.close();

    }
```

The ???????? is that I'm stuck there, maybe the whole method needs to be rewritten, I would appreciate your input.

Thanks

Comment: `the record stored in column3` a record is a full row. And DELETE works on full rows. So, ... maybe you have to re-think your database logic.

Comment: Ok and apparently this is my confusion, if I delete the row _id=5, that means that I will delete the data stored across the five columns in position 5 right??

Comment: Yes. All the columns in the record with _id = 5 will be deleted. The _id is **not** recycled (unless you don't manage it yourself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to delete the whole record, just use the _id of the record in delete method, because that is the primary key for your table and therefore is unique. If you'd rather keep the record, you con always use the SQLiteDatabase.update method, specifying null as the new value that will replace column3 value; check out that column3 declaration has no NOT NULL tag, otherwise that could easily throw exception at you.

Comment: Good advice, I think my confusion is of concept, if I delete the row in certain _id, am I deleting the whole row across all of the columns in the table?

Comment: Or simply replace the old value with a default one, such as `''` or `0`.

Comment: Exactly; the table only specifies what's inside it, and is a static element of a database. Rows (or records), on the other hand, can be created, edited and deleted, but they ALWAYS follow strictly the table definition, meaning you cannot erase a column completely, but you can specify, as noted before, special values resembling an empty value. I suggest you to read something about SQL databases; they are very useful, but you should focus on analisys and development before even begin implementation. Thanks for accepting the answer by the way :)

Answer (score 0):

`SQLite` does not allow you to delete columns for a specific row.
You can only delete ROWS of data (delete the row that has the column _ID = 1).

[Here](https://www.codeschool.com/courses/try-sql)'s a quick tutorial on `SQL`.

Comment: Thanks for the link, definitely I need to improve my database skills :)

Comment: Accept the answer if you find it useful. :)

Answer (score 0):

How about updating that column with a `null` value, rather than using `delete()`?

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.putNull(KEY_COLUMN3);

db.getWritableDatabase().update(
        TABLE_NAME,
        cv,
        KEY_ID + "=?",
        new String[]{String.valueOf(keyIdValue)});
```